# Different profiles for sound mixer?

Tags: 12.04, sound, hardware, pulseaudio, alsa

I'd like to switch between different ubuntu sound mixer profiles, depending on what sound hardware I plug in or wirelessly activate.

The easiest way I think I can do this would be to have a script for each profile, which sets the hardware and volume levels. Would alsa be the program I'd be writing a script for? Or would it be for something else? Or is it pulse audio? I'm kinda confused.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are no other answers, I will try to help with some remarks.

In general, it is possible to setup your system in such a way that plugging an audio interface (say, via USB) would trigger a change in, say, sound volume. For this you will need to:

1. create a new (or modify an existing) **Udev** rule so that plugging/unplugging a specific external soundcard launches a specific application (presumably a script).
2. create a **Bash** script that performs the necessary changes in the configuration of your sound system. For example, you might create several sound mixer profiles in different files, and have your script set a symlink to the desired profile.

Both steps are non-trivial, but realizable nonetheless.